# How to remove a directory in R?

Tags: r, directory

After some research I found out that the following works:

```
unlink("mydir")
```

and you have to use the `recursive` option in case you want to remove recursively:

```
unlink("mydir", recursive=TRUE)
```

However, I noted that `unlink("mydir")` alone, without the `recursive` option, does not produce any output when `mydir` contains subdirectories: it does not remove the dirs but does not show any warning. Just nothing:

```
> list.dirs()
[1] "."          "./r"
> dir.create("test")
> dir.create("test/test2")
> list.dirs()
[1] "."            "./r"   "./test"       "./test/test2"
> unlink("test")          ######### here I would expect a warning #########
> list.dirs()
[1] "."            "./r"   "./test"       "./test/test2"
> unlink("test", recursive=TRUE)
> list.dirs()
[1] "."          "./r"
```

Is there any way to get any kind of "notification", like the one you would get in UNIX systems?

```
$ rmdir test
rmdir: failed to remove «test»: Directory not empty
```

I am using R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31). I tried playing with `options(warn=1)` etc but no luck.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

See help `?unlink`:

> Value
>
> 0 for success, 1 for failure, invisibly. Not deleting a non-existent
>   file is not a failure, nor is being unable to delete a directory if
>   recursive = FALSE. However, missing values in x are regarded as
>   failures.

In the case where there is a folder `foo` the `unlink` call without `recursive=TRUE` will return `1`.

Note that actually the behavior is more like `rm -f`, which means that unlinking a non-existent file will return 0.

Comment: Interesting... I just tried it: effectively `> print(unlink("test"))` returns `[1] 1` and `> print(unlink("test", recursive=TRUE))` returns `[1] 0` because it was successful. Then this means that the only way to know if the deletion was effective is by catching the return code of the `unlink` command... I understand it but looks a bit counterintuitive.

Comment: Just to make it clear: To delete a folder you **have** to pass `recursive = TRUE` (see help for `unlink`: *If recursive = FALSE directories are not deleted, not even empty ones.*).

Answer (score 21):

Simply

```
unlink("mydir", recursive = TRUE) # will delete directory called 'mydir'
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's a wrapper function for you if you *really* need to see an error msg:

```
.unlink <- function(x, recursive = FALSE, force = FALSE) {
  if (unlink(x, recursive, force) == 0)
    return(invisible(TRUE))
  stop(sprintf("Failed to remove [%s]", x))
}
```

Comment: you could make it `unlink <-` and do `base::unlink` in the actual function, but that just seems wrong. if you have automated scripts that need to know if a dir is deleted, then I'd just test the return value.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you! I am just beginning with R, so I will need to read the code carefully to fully understand all the functions you use :)

Answer (score 1):

For those stumbling on this, I normally resort to using 'shell' command here to completely delete the folder.

Using 'system' will print a 127 error if the folder is non-empty.

The following is the simple nuclear option - deleting the folder in its entirety (no questions asked):

```
Loc <- "C:/file has spaces/hence the form below/"
shell( glue::glue("rmdir /s /q \"{Loc}\" ") )
```